# Как узнать номер телефона?

Tags: android, java

Хочу узнать номер телефона, использую стандартный метод, но возвращает null:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В интернетах говорят, что это единственный способ. Который работает не всегда. Говорят, что работает только в тех случаях, когда номер телефона записан в сим-карте. Если не записан (например, операторский телефон, который без симки работает, и т. п.) - номер получить не удастся. Буду рад ошибаться...

Comment: спасибо, надеюсь, есть какой-нибудь способ еще,  у меня телефон с сим-картой от теле2.

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего больше никак. Аналогично у вас номер и в настройках телефона не отображается. У меня то же самое было на всех симках Теле2.